# Jquery .find() returning undefined within Backbone view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

Im unit testing a function in a Backbone view (called DialogView) with Jasmine.js. The function to test in DialogView is:

```
    wireScroll: function() {
        var self = this;
        var wrapper = self.$el.find('.iscrollWrapper').get(0);

        ...

    },
```

I want to check that .find is called.

```
    it('jquery find called', function () {
        theView = new DialogView();
        theView.render();

        spyOn($.fn, 'find');
        theView.wireScroll();
        expect($.fn.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

However, I get a very strange problem in the view:

```
 Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

So in the view, the .find() fails and therefore the .get() fails. So I did some tests and logs:

```
     it('jquery find called', function () {

        theView = new DialogView();
        theView.render();

        console.log('in unit test and theView.$el[0].outerHTML is ');
        console.log(theView.$el[0].outerHTML);

        console.log('in unit test, finding .iscrollWrapper');
        console.log(theView.$el.find('.iscrollWrapper'));

    });
```

And in the view:

```
    wireScroll: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log('in wireScroll and self.$el[0].outerHTML is ');
        console.log(self.$el[0].outerHTML);

        console.log('in wireScroll, finding .iscrollWrapper');
        console.log(self.$el.find('.iscrollWrapper'));
    },
```

The result of outerHTML in the unit test and the view is, predictably, identical. Both contain a div element with class of 'iscrollWrapper'.

In the unit test, the result of the log for .find() is:

```
in unit test, finding .iscrollWrapper 
[div.iscrollWrapper, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: undefined, selector: ".iscrollWrapper", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

However, in the view, I get:

```
in wireScroll, finding .iscrollWrapper 
undefined
```

This makes no sense as the outerHTML log for both shows there is a div with a class of "iscrollWrapper". Any ideas what could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I left out the andCallThrough() at the end of spyOn(). So it should be:

```
spyOn($.fn, 'find').andCallThrough();
```

It's working now.